# Is it possible to turn that into '<script setup>' ? I try many ways but missing something maybe

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-script-setup

Is it possible to turn that into `<script setup>` ? I try many ways but missing something maybe. Need help !

```html
<script>
    import ProductsAPI from '../api/products.api';

    export default {
        name: 'products',

        components: {
            product: 'product',
        },

        data() {
            return {
                products: [],
                error: '',
            };
        },

        async created() {
            this.products = await ProductsAPI.fetchAll();
        },
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Trying by a normal way, but I got a lot of problems, such as my promise which doesn't resolve (stay pending)... The variable 'products' which seems to be scoped and not accessible outside the function...

Answer (score 9):

It helps to break the problem down into smaller problems that can be tackled individually...

### Component registration

Components are automatically registered upon importing their definition in a `<script setup>`, so registering `Product` is trivial:

```html
<script setup>
import Product from '@/components/Product.vue' // locally registered
</script>
```

### Data properties

Reactive data properties are declared as [`ref`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/refs-api.html#ref) (or [`reactive`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/basic-reactivity.html#reactive)):

```html
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

const products = ref([])
const error = ref('')

// to change the value of the `ref`, use its `.value` property
error.value = 'My error message'
products.value = [{ name: 'Product A' }, { name: 'Product B' }]
</script>
```

Alternatively, you can use the new/experimental [Reactivity Transform](https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/discussions/369) in `<script setup>`, which globally defines the reactivity APIs, prefixed with `$` (e.g., `$ref` for `ref`), and avoids having to unwrap `ref`s via `.value`:

```html
<script setup>
let products = $ref([])
let error = $ref('')

// assign the values directly (no need for .value)
error = 'My error message'
products = [{ name: 'Product A' }, { name: 'Product B' }]
</script>
```

### `created` lifecycle hook

The `<script setup>` block occurs in the same timing as the `setup` hook, which is also the same timing as the `created` hook, so you could copy your original hook code there. To use `await`, you could either wrap the call in an `async` [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE):

```html
<script setup>
import ProductAPI from '@/api/products.api'
import { ref } from 'vue'

const products = ref([])

;(async () => {
  products.value = await ProductAPI.fetchAll()
})()
</script>
```

...or create an `async` function that is called therein:

```html
<script setup>
import ProductAPI from '@/api/products.api'
import { ref } from 'vue'

const products = ref([])

const loadProducts = async () => products.value = await ProductAPI.fetchAll()
loadProducts()
</script>
```

### Component name

There's no equivalent Composition API for the `name` property, but you can use a `<script>` block in addition to `<script setup>` in the same SFC to contain any props that are not supported by the Composition API:

```html
<script setup>
⋮
</script>

<!-- OK to have <script> and <script setup> in same SFC -->
<script>
export default {
  name: 'products',
}
</script>
```

Alternatively, you can specify the component's name via its filename. This [feature](https://github.com/vuejs/core/pull/4997) was added in [`v3.2.34-beta.1`](https://github.com/vuejs/core/releases/tag/v3.2.34-beta.1). For example, a component with `<script setup>` whose filename is `MyComponent.vue` would have a name of `MyComponent`.

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-converting-to-script-setup?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FProducts.vue)

Comment: NB: reactivity transform is now deprecated. Cf https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/reactivity-transform.html

Answer (score 4):

you should import the component before registering it.

```
<script>
import ProductsAPI from '../api/products.api';
import ProductComp from './components/Product.vue'

export default {
    name: 'products',

    components: {
        'product': ProductComp
    },

    data() {
        return {
            products: [],
            error: '',
        };
    },

    async created() {
        this.products = await ProductsAPI.fetchAll();
    },
};
```

Using script setup would look something like this.

```
 <script setup>
   import ProductsAPI from '../api/products.api';
   import Product from './components/Product.vue'

   let error = '';
   let products = await ProductsAPI.fetchAll();
</script>
```

Comment: They aren't equivalent.  The second snippet results in async component that uses suspense

Answer (score 1):

The problem is specific to composition API, not specifically `script setup`. As long as a component is properly written, `script` can, with few exceptions, be easily transformed to `script setup` by extracting the content of `setup` while preserving imports and `setup` return values.

The [lifecycle](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-lifecycle-hooks.html) in composition API has close but not direct counterpart to `created` hook. And the problem is that `created` was initially misused. Vue heavily borrows from React and has a similar lifecycle, the latter has strict rules regarding the use of side effects on component creation. All side effects are supposed to be performed later when a component has been already mounted.

Vue doesn't have the same technical limitations as React, but some concerns are also applicable. There are just not enough reasons to do side effects in `created`, so they belong to `mounted`. There are little to no advantages to have them in `created`, while the disadvantages are that initial rendering is blocked by a work that could be done later on component mount, and the side effects that are done too early on component creation may result in problems in SSR due to its semantics, and then there are problems with `script setup`. Also there is clear semantics for `mounted` and `unmounted` hooks, the latter may do a cleanup for side effects that occur in the former.

In both `script setup` and `script` with `setup` function, it can be:

```
let products = ref([]);

onMounted(async () => {
  products.value = await ProductsAPI.fetchAll();
});
```

TL;DR: It's a good practice to use `mounted` and not `created` lifecycle hook for asynchronous side effects. `mounted` is available in `script setup`.

Comment: Is there an import missing? I'm getting `ReferenceError: onMounted is not defined` - perhaps `import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue'`

Comment: Yes. As said, imports need to be maintained with script setup syntax. This doesn't differ from the use of composition API in general.