# How do I update a watched property in a Vue "script setup" script?

Tags: vue.js

I am new to the version of Vue that introduced the "script setup" tag. I would like to trigger a watcher to update the `season` property and then calculate a new value based on that input. You can see it happening here:

```js
  watch(season, () => {
    getStandings(season)
  }, { immediate: true })
```

I am trying to trigger the watcher from within a function that is triggered by a child component emitting an event with data. You can see it here:

```html
// in the template
<SeasonSelect :season="season" @changedOption="onChangeSelection"/>

// and then in the script
    function onChangeSelection(selection: number) {
        console.log(selection, 8);
        this.season = selection; // i tried this, this is what I expected to work
    }
```

What I want is for the `selection` parameter to make it into the watcher. If it goes there, the watcher should take care of the computation as I intend.

Please tell me directly how to handle this. There isn't a lot of findable info about how to handle the special case where "script setup" is used.

Here is the full code for this component, which is the main component called `index.vue`:

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
  import { useDPC } from '@/composables/useDPC';
  import { CONFIGS } from '@/configs';

  import SeasonSelect from '../components/SeasonSelect.vue';



    function onChangeSelection(selection: number) {
        console.log(selection, 8);
        this.season = selection;
    }

  const season = $ref<number>(CONFIGS.SEASONS.THE_INTERNATIONAL_11)
  const { standings, getStandings, isLoading } = useDPC()

  watch(season, () => {
    getStandings(season)
  }, { immediate: true })
</script>

<template>
  <div>

    <SeasonSelect :season="season" @changedOption="onChangeSelection"/>
    <h1>DPC Standings for {{ season }} season</h1>

    <h2 v-if="isLoading">
      Loading...
    </h2>
    <ul v-else>
        <div v-for="team in standings" :key="team.team_id">
            <Team :team="team"/>
        </div>

    </ul>
  </div>
</template>
```

edit: please note that [the official documentation page about "script setup"](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html) doesn't mention how to implement a watcher or update a watcher, and *everything* is different in a "script setup" file

edit2: Per request of  Boussadjra Brahim here is the code for SeasonSelect

```
<script>
    import { CONFIGS } from '../configs';

console.log(CONFIGS, 4);
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                seasons: Object.assign({},CONFIGS.SEASONS)
            }
        },
        props: {
            season: Number
        },
        methods: {
            onChange(event) {
                console.log(event.target.value, 16)
                this.$emit("changedOption", event.target.value);
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<template>
    <select v-model="season" name="season" @change="onChange($event)">
      <option v-for="(value, key) in seasons" :key="key" :value="value">
        {{ key }}
      </option>
    </select>
</template>
```

Third edit: Like yo even [this detailed breakdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70549941/is-it-possible-to-turn-that-into-script-setup-i-try-many-ways-but-missing) doesnt mention anything about using watched properties in the "script setup" version of a SFC

Comment: to trigger watch you should change season  value by assign new value which come from child cmp But to assign new value to ref  ->  season.value = selection;

Comment: and watch in vue 3 check this https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html#basic-example

Comment: Please share the all code of `SeasonSelect ` component

Comment: Still not answered with a solution but, I have since figured out how to abandon using ```setup``` in my script tag. I'm now using a standard SFC using just ```<script></script>```

Answer (score -1):

When you are using `<script setup>`, it does not mean that you don't need to import necessary stuffs to your codes. You did not import `watch` in your parent component that uses `<script setup>`. Also `this.season` is not correct in `<script setup>`. Here is a basic example on how to manage your `<select>` operation in a `<script setup>` way:

> parent component:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <SeasonSelect :season="season" @changedOption="onChangeSelection"/>
    <h1>DPC Standings for {{ season }} season</h1>

<!--    <h2 v-if="isLoading">-->
<!--      Loading...-->
<!--    </h2>-->
<!--    <ul v-else>-->
<!--      <div v-for="team in standings" :key="team.team_id">-->
<!--        <Team :team="team"/>-->
<!--      </div>-->

<!--    </ul>-->
  </div>
</template>


<script setup>
// import { useDPC } from '@/composables/useDPC';
// import { CONFIGS } from '@/configs';

// -------------------------------------------
/* importing things that are necessary from vue */
// -------------------------------------------
import {watch, ref} from "vue";

import SeasonSelect from '../components/SeasonSelect.vue';

const season = ref("value1");

function onChangeSelection(selection) {
  console.log(selection, 8);
  season.value = selection;
}


// const season = $ref<number>(CONFIGS.SEASONS.THE_INTERNATIONAL_11)
// const { standings, getStandings, isLoading } = useDPC()

watch(season, () => {
  console.log("season watch")
})
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

> child component:

```html
<template>
  <select v-model="season" name="season" @change="onChange($event)">
    <option v-for="(value, key) in seasons" :key="key" :value="value">
      {{ key }}
    </option>
  </select>
</template>

<script>
// import { CONFIGS } from '../configs';

// console.log(CONFIGS, 4);
export default {
  name: "SeasonSelect",
  data() {
    return {
      /* I used a simple object to demonstrate the way you can implement this code. */
      seasons: {
        key1: "value1",
        key2: "value2",
        key3: "value3"
      }
    }
  },
  props: {
    season: String
  },
  methods: {
    onChange(event) {
      console.log(event.target.value, 16)
      this.$emit("changedOption", event.target.value);
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

I also removed some features like using `lang="ts"`, because they are not related to your question here.